# Xamarin iOS 15 crashes on orientation changes (Device only)

Tags: xamarin.ios

I stumbled across a really annoying thing happening during the development of my Xamarin.Forms app on iOS devices:

Everything works fine on Android - reacting to orientation changes works like a charm.

Starting the App in Portrait or Landscape mode works perfectly fine.

But as soon as I rotate the device on iOS: the app gets stuck, filling half of the screen available and has to be restarted to work again.

It happens every single time. Eventhough the "supports multi tasking" setting is disabled and all device-orientation-flags are set for both: iPhone and iPad.

I couldn't find anything up to date on that issue.

Any suggestions how to overcome this bug?

Comment: Is it on ios15 only? have you test it on other version？

Comment: Hey, thanks for joining in! Since I have no iOS-Device with an older iOS-Version: no. What's weird is the fact, that on iOS-Simulators everything works fine.

Comment: @ItsAMysterious Did you find any solution?

Comment: Not a satisfying one, no :/ For now, I locked the screen orientation to Portrait (which is the orientation used most on smartphones) and manually rotate the views which are better to be viewed in portrait mode.